# facebook->getUser() give back always 0

Tags: oauth, facebook-php-sdk

I have the same problem like many others that the method getUser() in the php-sdk give back allways zero. 
I find out that the reason for this, is an condition in the method parseSignedRequest().

```
if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
  self::errorLog('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
  return NULL;
}
```

The Condition is allways true. When I uncomment this condition it works fine. I get the correct user and I also can fetch a token with all permisson where I ask for.

But I fell uncomfortable with this dirty solution. Why can it be. Is there perhaps a misconfiguration on the Server.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same problem.. has taken me 4 days to track it down...

Here's the result of my debug echo of the conditional, where you have $sig being compared to $expected_sig.

sig: [�ꢖ�b��u����f�^��4֣�GP�

expected sig: ��{��.��nwW�:�r��B�����C8$��%F

So for some reason, the signature being sent is NOT matching up with any of the expected encoded signatures.

So I was wondering... what could be wrong here?

Could it be I'm not passing in the proper "Secret" even though I'm setting it up right in my config?

```
require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = $APP_ID;
$config[‘secret’] = $APP_SECRET;
$config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
```

As it turns out, when I use

```
$facebook->getAppID();
```

or

```
$facebook->getAppSecret();
```

NOTHING is being returned!

THIS is why my getSignedRequestCookieName() function returns only "fbsr_"

THIS is why

```
$expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload,
                          $facebook->getAppSecret(), $raw = true);
```

returns the wrong hash!

BUT WHY?

Simple answer: a badly formed config array...

Using "$config[‘appId’] = $APP_ID;"... notice the quotes around "appId".  This was a direct copy/paste from the docs/examples on the facebook developer docs.

Replace those quotes with standard double quotes

```
$config = array();
$config["appId"] = $APP_ID;
$config["secret"] = $APP_SECRET;
$config["fileUpload"] = false; // optional
```

... here's the results:

sig: r�0��g%���ͦ��w�(�B^���Ddv

expected sig: r�0��g%���ͦ��w�(�B^���Ddv

They now match...

Long story short... do a phpinfo() to make sure you're getting a signed_request token... if you are sure you are getting that (or the "$*REQUEST[fbsr*#######]" var)... if you're SURE you're getting an encoded signed request... the only reason your hash won't match is if you're not getting the right secret in there.